# Turn a ClickOnce published app into standalone?

Tags: .net, clickonce, installation, inno-setup

I'm trying to figure out how to turn the result of publishing an app with ClickOnce (with the Install from CD-ROM option) into a standalone .exe file that would extract the files into a temporary folder and run "setup.exe". I'm not sure if I can get Inno Setup to do that for me, or if I should create a Win32 (not managed, since the user might not have the .net framework installed yet) with my files embed in it, somehow, and then, somehow extract them and run "setup.exe" programmatically. I don't know, maybe there is an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Take all the files created by ClickOnce (the "setup.exe", the "MyApp.application" and all the files inside the "Application Files" folder) and somehow put them into a singe .exe file that would extract them and run the "setup.exe".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inno setup you can put a lot of files into a single exe and execute any of these files during setup.

A installer inside a installer will require you to check everything works well.  For example you may want this inno setup installer does not register a uninstaller (because the ClickOnce may register the correct one).

Unfortunately you question is to vague to provide a more specific answer.  As starting point you should download [inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and take a look at the examples:

setup.iss will show a lot of inno capabilities.  Pay attention and how to include and run files: [Files] and [Run] sections of the script.